# Cocoapods (private) unable to find specification

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, cocoapods

We have private cocoapods. When I type `pod repo`:

```
company-private
- Type: git (origin)
- URL:  ssh://me@myCompany.com//path/git/PrivateCocoapods
- Path: /Users/Username/.cocoapods/repos/company-private

master
- Type: git (origin)
- URL:  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
- Path: /Users/Username/.cocoapods/repos/master
```

I've entered `~/.cocoapods/repos`:

```
$ ls
company-private  master
$ cd company-private
$ ls
Specs
$ cd Specs:
$ ls
MyProject
$ cd MyProject:
$ ls
0.0.19  0.0.2  0.0.5
$ cd /0.0.5:
$ ls
MyProject.podspec
```

In another project `.podfile` I'm trying to:

```
pod 'MyProject', '0.0.5'
```

And after `pod install` or `pod update` I receive:

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `MyProject (= 0.0.5)`
```

Does anybody have any idea why it doesn't work..?

--- edit ---

I can reproduce it on any computer by simply typing `pod install`. It wasn't working like this previously. I've used `pod repo push company-private MyProject.podspec` to push to the server. It was working a week ago. Today I've pushed new version with the same way, but with `--allow-warnings` flag. When I've tried to bump to version `0.0.19` it wasn't already working. I've cloned the repo and added Spec folder meantime (so you can see it now on `ls`), but it still isn't working.

-- edit2 --

Output of verbose:

```
$ pod install --verbose
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Updating spec repositories
  $ /usr/local/bin/git rev-parse  >/dev/null 2>&1
  $ /usr/local/bin/git rev-parse  >/dev/null 2>&1
Updating spec repo `master`
  $ /usr/local/bin/git pull --ff-only
  From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
     4715d39..f21e61b  master     -> origin/master
  Updating 4715d39..f21e61b
  Fast-forward
   Specs/ISO8601-re2c/0.3.1/ISO8601-re2c.podspec.json | 24 ++++++
   Specs/Mobily/2.0.77/Mobily.podspec.json            | 91 ++++++++++++++++++++++
   Specs/NJISO8601/0.2.2/NJISO8601.podspec.json       | 22 ++++++
   3 files changed, 137 insertions(+)
   create mode 100644 Specs/ISO8601-re2c/0.3.1/ISO8601-re2c.podspec.json
   create mode 100644 Specs/Mobily/2.0.77/Mobily.podspec.json
   create mode 100644 Specs/NJISO8601/0.2.2/NJISO8601.podspec.json

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  - MyProject

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
Finished resolution (0 steps) (Took 0.006555 seconds) (2015-03-13 15:06:41 +0100)
[!] Unable to find a specification for `MyProject (= 0.0.5)`
```

Comment: What version of cocoapods are you using? This happened to me while trying `0.36.0` beta version - it requires to explicitly specify source repository in podfile

Comment: @JakubVano Yes exactly. I've just updated to 0.36.0. Atm I'm reporting the issue on their github. Because it shouldn't work like this?

Comment: I am pretty sure i have read somewhere, that this is intended behaviour - it has to do with some existing pods not being compatible with new building into frameworks functionality

Comment: @JakubVano Hm. I've already added an issue. Didn't see that information. Anyway, I'll leave the question and the issue for other people. Someone may have the same issue and wonder what's happening. https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/issues/13007

Comment: @JakubVano Please post as an answer that you need to attack source like eg `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` but with link to private pods - I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cocoapods version 0.36.0 requires you to explicitly specify source repository in your Podfile, e.g.:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

Comment: Tested on 0.37.0. Explicit source is still required.